# IntelliJ Maven Project - new file reverting to read only

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, cucumber

I've created a new IntelliJ Maven project for use with Cucumber / Java. I've encountered an issue whereby if I create a new .feature file, the file is marked 'read only'. If I then select 'File -> Make Writable', as soon as I start typing in the file, it reverts to read only and errors with 'File is not writable'! I'm getting the same issue if I use the little padlock icon in the bottom right hand corner. Anyone have any ideas on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the full path to the file? Where does it reside in terms of IntelliJ IDEA module roots? Source root/library root? Is it a Google Drive or OneDrive folder? What file system is used? What are the FS permissions for this directory?

Comment: Im just creating a new file inside the IDEA, under project root. I've created the src folder under the root as it wasn't automatically created when I created the project - I think due possibly to proxy issues within the company I'm working at. I am surmising this as I had similar errors when trying to pull in dependencies (now resolved). Through windows explorer the permissions are showing as myself having full control. However, 'read only' is ticked. If I untick this, then select 'apply to this folder', it reverts to read only as soon as I go back in to view permissions.

Comment: I should add that it is the top level folder that is showing as 'read only' in explorer - the src folder. My feature file within that folder is not showing as read only at any point.